# Objective-C @implementation variables visibility

Tags: objective-c, variables, implementation

I got two classes, which implementation contains an array named "geometryCoords", in "Corridor" class it is initialized in declaration, and in "RhombusArray" it is done in the "init" method:

```
GLfloat _geometryCoords[]={/*Values here*/};
```

---

```
GLfloat _geometryCoords[];
...//In the init method
_geometryCoords = (GLfloat*)malloc(somevalue);
for(...){/*Assignment*/}
```

While debugging this method i noticed that "geometryCoords" has the values of the first class' array before the initialization code is passed. After changing the declaration of array in "RhombusArray" from:

```
GLfloat _geometryCoords[];
```

to

```
GLfloat* _geometryCoords;
```

i got an "Apple Mach-o linker error: duplicate symbol _geometryCoords in /BlaBla/Corridor.o and /BlaBla/RhombusArray.o". 
Both of those classes' headers are imported to the .mm file and removing one of them solves the conflict. 
How should i handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these arrays must have global scope (i.e. they are declared outside of a function and outside of a class interface) for you to get the linker error and the other issue.  Declare them like this:

```
static GLfloat _geometryCoords[]={/*Values here*/};
//^^^^ this is the new bit
```

The `static` keyword makes the symbol visible only within the compilation unit (the `.m` file) in which they are declared.